# Excel: How to Copy Hlookup position down?

Tags: excel

I have an Hlookup formula and was trying to copy it down but the position number doesn't change. I Would like to be able to copy it down to other cells and need the position to change by 1 for each cell.

```
Hlookup(A1,B1:D20,2,False)
```

When I copy the formula down , I need 2 to become 3. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The function `ROW()` returns the number of the row the cell is on, you can offset it to obtain the right number.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps add another column to refer to as this number? Then, have this column increment by one either by formula or using Excel to do it for you. Thus, if your formula was in cell A2:

```
// in cell
E1: 2

// in cell (and copied down)
E2: =E1+1
```

Then, in the cell you mentioned, the formula would become something like:

```
=hlookup(A1,B1:D20,E1,False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest why to do that is to have a column with the return position you want. So:

```
Hlookup(A1,B1:D20,zz1,False)

cell zz1 has: 2
cell zz2 has: 3

etc...
```

If you don't like that you can add 2 plus row() and maybe subtract to get where you want when you copy.

Comment: That is exactly what I did

Comment: Yes it did . Thanks you